# Casting IEnumerable<T> back to original type with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

If I have the following how to do I cast the result of the lambda expression back to the Customer type from `IEnumerable<Customer>` without having to iterate over it.

```
public class Customer : CustomerModel
{
    public List<Customer> CustomerList {get;set;}

    public Customer GetCustomerFromListById(long id)
    {
        return CustomerList.Select(c => c).Where(i => i.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing `.Select(c => c)` is redundant, you can remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use .Single(), also Select is redundant:

```
return CustomerList.Single(i => i.Id == id);
```

As mentioned in the comments that way you get an exception if it doesn't contain the needed key, which should be the expected behavior.

Comment: +1, `Single` is the more appropriate operator for finding by a primary key.

Comment: May note that single throws an exception... that is often a source of surprise and frustration to new LINQ users.

Comment: @Rex, your comment is worth mentioning, but I wouldn't use it for querying by primary key.  If it's not found, that's a serious error and *should* be an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Use FirstOrDefault().

```
   return CustomerList.Select(c => c).Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Even better. Use the overload on FirstOrDefault that takes the `Func<T,bool>` lambda directly as argument